# How much XP does it take to get to level 30?

Tags: league-of-legends

Level 30 is the max level for a Summoner, but how much XP does it take to get there? About how many 5v5 matches does it take to get that much (assuming 50% win/loss ratio)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According [to the wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_%28summoner%29), it takes 40083xp.

Also from the wiki:

> Assuming an average XP gain to be about 110 XP per game, one can reach summoner level 30 within 365 normal games.

Comment: with a game averaging at 30 minutes, 365 games is A LOT.

Comment: Please note these are averages as best as they could be given. There are the first win of the day bonuses, each one varries but a bit for quick win, long defense, etc. They run promotions all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous response, you can purchase XP boosts from the store to help you gain more points per win if you are really interested to get to level 30 faster.  Please understand the competition for the most part have won about 150 games to level 30 so the faster you progress the less time you have to develop the necessary skills to play at the higher level.